# How to make a give gui button on roblox studio?

Tags: lua, roblox

i want to know how could i make a give gui button, For example, if I have a "textbutton" and I press it near another player, the button disappear from my gui and the other player has it? any idea how i do it?

pls i have searched everywhere and I can not find any solution..

How this works

**My player has a "textbutton" in his gui, If i approach another player and I press my "textbutton" it is given to the other player and in my gui it disappears, how do I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't find a solution because you're doing the same mistake 95% of all roblox guys and most other people posting here do. you're trying to find a solution to your very specific personal problem. but you have to break your problem down into atomic (very common) subproblems. Otherwise chances someone has done and documented the same online are close to 0.

- Make a gui visible to specific player
- Create a button
- React to a button press
- Find out who pressed the button
- Calculate the distance between two players
- Calculate the nearst player
- Remove a button from the GUI
- Add a button to the GUI

You will find plenty of information on how to solve these problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot! and sorry for the inconvenience, what happens is that I read the documentation but it does not always help me at all since I am something new programming in this engine..